# Find minimum value of $\sum \frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b +\sqrt c-\sqrt a}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

> Find the minimum value of $$\sum \frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b +\sqrt c-\sqrt a}$$
>   Where $a, b, c$ represent the sides of a triangle

*My approach*

$$\sum \frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b +\sqrt c-\sqrt a}$$
$$=\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt {\frac ba} +\sqrt {\frac ca}-1}$$
By Titu's lemma

$$=\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt {\frac ba} +\sqrt {\frac ca}-1}\ge \frac {9}{\left ( \sum \sqrt {\frac ba}+ \sqrt {\frac ab}\right)-3}$$

Now by Cauchy Schwarz inequality 
$$\left ( \sum \sqrt {\frac ba}+ \sqrt {\frac ab}\right)^2 \le \left (\sum \frac ab +\frac ba\right)(6)$$
Hence we have 
$$=\sum \frac {1}{\sqrt {\frac ba} +\sqrt {\frac ca}-1}\ge \frac {9}{\left ( \sum \sqrt {\frac ba}+ \sqrt {\frac ab}\right)-3}\ge \frac {9}{\sqrt {\left (\sum \frac ab +\frac ba\right)(6)}-3}$$

Now how to proceed further.